# Difference between while(true) in Coroutine then put it in the void Start() and not having while(true) but put it in the void Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, coroutine

I'm trying to make the game spawn enemies every random period of time so I'm using `yield return new WaitForSeconds(...)` in Coroutine and as the title says, I can use `while(true)` inside the Coroutine and call the Coroutine in the `void Start()` and the spawning thing works just fine. But when i removed the `while(true)` and call the Coroutine in `void Update()`, the enemies are spawned crazily without the delay. Why is this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I guess you don't wait but rather start a new concurrent routine **every frame** so after the delay has passed once at the beginning you now get one call for each frame!

A Coroutine does **not** delay the outer code which starts it.

Either use e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private float delay;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Routine);
}

private IEnumerator Routine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

or also directly

```
// If you make Start an IEnumerator then Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine 
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want to go for `Update` the equivalent would require a counter like e.g.

```
private float timer;

private void Start()
{
    timer = delay;
}

private void Udpate()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer <= 0)
    {
        DoSomething();
        timer = delay;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't mix both things ;)

And personally I find Coroutines better to read and maintain most of the times.

Comment: Oh oh, I see. So that means that if I put the Coroutine with while(true) in the void Start() like that it's gonna stuck in the while loop in the Coroutine in the Start() forever right?

Comment: yesn't ;) `stuck` sounds like a freeze ^^ A Coroutine basically gets called `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` once a frame right after `Update` finished .. and then it runs until the next `yield` statement